# Eclipse RCP : Clean and update maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I clone and import an archetype to make a new project.
I clone and import parents projects too.
After all they are errors in the workspace because it need clean and update maven.

I need to launch clean and update from an IWorkspaceRoot or IProject.
If you have an other way it would be great too.

Something like the refresh IProject.refreshLocal(...)